# How to substitute strings in JSON with jq based on the input

Tags: json, jq

Given the input in this form

```
[
  {
    "DIR" : "/foo/bar/a/b/c",
    "OUT" : "/foo/bar/x/y/z",
    "ARG" : [ "aaa", "bbb", "/foo/bar/a", "BASE=/foo/bar" ]
  },
  {
    "DIR" : "/foo/baz/d/e/f",
    "OUT" : "/foo/baz/x/y/z",
    "ARG" : [ "ccc", "ddd", "/foo/baz/b", "BASE=/foo/baz" ]
  },
  { 
    "foo" : "bar"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to find out how to make jq transform that into this:

```
[
  {
    "DIR" : "BASE/a/b/c",
    "OUT" : "BASE/x/y/z",
    "ARG" : [ "aaa", "bbb", "BASE/a", "BASE=/foo/bar" ]
  },

  {
    "DIR" : "BASE/d/e/f",
    "OUT" : "BASE/x/y/z",
    "ARG" : [ "ccc", "ddd", "BASE/b", "BASE=/foo/baz" ]
  },
  { 
    "foo" : "bar"
  }
]
```

In other words, objects having an `"ARG"` array, containing a string that starts with `"BASE="` should use the string after `"BASE="`, e.g. `"/foo"` to substitute other string values that start with "`/foo"` (except the `"BASE=/foo"` which should remain unchanged")

I'm not even close to finding a solution myself, and at this point I'm unsure that jq alone will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jq`:

```
#!/usr/bin/jq -f

# fix-base.jq
def fix_base:
  (.ARG[] | select(startswith("BASE=")) | split("=")[1]) as $base
  | .DIR?|="BASE"+ltrimstr($base)
  | .OUT?|="BASE"+ltrimstr($base)
  | .ARG|=map(if startswith($base) then "BASE"+ltrimstr($base) else . end)
  ;

map(if .ARG? then fix_base  else . end)
```

You can run it like this:

```
jq -f fix-base.jq input.json
```

or make it an executable like this:

```
chmod +x fix-base.jq
./fix-base.jq input.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, **`jq`** alone will do the job:

```
jq 'def sub_base($base): if (startswith("BASE") | not) then sub($base; "BASE") else . end;
    map(if .["ARG"] then ((.ARG[] | select(startswith("BASE=")) | split("=")[1]) as $base
            | to_entries
            | map(if (.value | type == "string") then .value |= sub_base($base)
                  else .value |= map(sub_base($base)) end)
            | from_entries)
        else . end)' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "DIR": "BASE/a/b/c",
    "OUT": "BASE/x/y/z",
    "ARG": [
      "aaa",
      "bbb",
      "BASE/a",
      "BASE=/foo/bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "DIR": "BASE/d/e/f",
    "OUT": "BASE/x/y/z",
    "ARG": [
      "ccc",
      "ddd",
      "BASE/b",
      "BASE=/foo/baz"
    ]
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some helper functions make the going much easier.  The first is generic and worthy perhaps of your standard library:

```
# Returns the integer index, $i, corresponding to the first element
# at which f is truthy, else null
def indexof(f):
  label $out
  | foreach .[] as $x (null; .+1; 
      if ($x|f) then (.-1, break $out) else empty end) // null;

# Change the string $base to BASE using gsub
def munge($base):
  if type == "string" and (test("^BASE=")|not) then gsub($base; "BASE")
  elif type=="array" then map(munge($base))
  elif type=="object" then map_values(munge($base))
  else .
  end;
```

And now the easy part:

```
map(if has("ARG") 
    then (.ARG|indexof(test("^BASE="))) as $ix
    | if $ix
      then (.ARG[$ix]|sub("^BASE=";"")) as $base | munge($base)
      else . end 
    else . end )
```

Some points to note:

- You may wish to use `sub` rather than `gsub` in `munge`;
- The above solution assumes you want to make the change in all keys, not just "DIR", "OUT", and "ARG"
- The above solution allows specifications of BASE that include one or more occurrences of "=".